# reindexing issue for catalog product flat

Tags: reindex

I am facing the catalog product flat reindexing issue in my project. I have tried many solution, but can't get any success. I have tried following solutions around Google:

1- I truncated all the `catelog_producr_flat` tables(like `catalog_product_flat_1`, `catalog_product_flat_2`, `catalog_product_flat_3`), and then clear all the cache and then reindexing. but not get any success

2- I changed the var/locks folder permission to 777 and empty that folder,then clear all the cache. Then try to **reindex**, but not success.

3- I tried manually reindex via following code given below and then clear all the cache , but not get any success:

```
<?php 
 require_once 'app/Mage.php'; 
 $app = Mage::app('admin'); 
 umask(0); 
 for ($index = 1; $index <= 8; $index++) { 
     $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($index); 
     $process->reindexAll(); 
 }
 ?>
```

4- Increase your execution time value in the **.htaccess** file and then clear all the cache, as below

> php_value memory_limit 128M
>
> php_value max_execution_time 18000

i have tried all the process but can't get any success, pleas help me.

Comment: Did you by any chance figure out the problem, seems like I having the same exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no any  proper solution. But i found a 3rd party extension "Aitoc" in my project, after disabling it, my problem solved.